# I am trying to save QImage with gif format

Tags: qt, visual-c++

I am trying to save QImage with gif format but getting the error
QImageIO::write: No such image format handler: GIF

Here is my code

```
'QImage image;
QByteArray ba;
QBuffer buffer(&ba);
buffer.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly);
image.save(&buffer, "GIF");'
```

any suggestion will be highly appreciable.

Comment: Try this https://github.com/dbzhang800/QtGifImage

Answer (score 2):

It is specified at the [reading and writing files](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qimage.html#reading-and-writing-image-files) section of `QImage` that Qt doesn't have support for writing "GIF" files by default. You should look for a third party library which implements this feature.

Comment: Exactly what should i need to do.

Comment: Also qt gif plugin would be heplful search query